# How do I format a Hiveos drive to instead be used by Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I had an 870 EVO SSD running Hiveos and now I want to install Windows on it. I tried doing so but the Windows installation media wouldn't let me select the drive to use it, I forget what the error was, something like Drive 0 Partition 0 can't be used. What do I need to do to my drive so that I can install Windows on it? I already tried formatting and recreating the first partition shown in the image as NTFS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you formatted some of the logical partitions, but you didn't really remove those partitions.
The current partition layout, with 2 very small partitions at the beginning of the drive, is not suitable for Windows.

The easiest thing to do is during the Windows install, where you need to select the drive, first to select each existing partition and remove it.
When the SSD is really empty simply select the empty drive. Windows will make a new, suitable, partition table and continue the installation.
(This will also fix the problem that you may be trying to install Windows in UEFI mode, which needs a GPT type partition table, but the SSD may currently be using a MBR type partition table.)

Just make sure you don't accidentally delete the installation media itself. Pay attention to drive-numbers and sizes shown in the drive-selection wizard, so you don't remove the wrong one(s).

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the HiveOS drive is the only one plugged into your computer when doing this.

For steps 1-3 you'll need another Windows machine to create your USB installation media.

1. Download Windows 10 ISO
2. Download and install [Rufus USB Boot utility](https://rufus.ie/en/)
3. Insert a 16GB USB Drive > open rufus > select Windows ISO > START
4. Restart your computer > Go to Boot menu > Boot from the Win10 USB you just made

- **Be warned** this next part is going wipe everything on that HiveOS drive

5. Select each partition displayed in the Windows Setup screen > Click "Delete"

*If this area is shows up empty you need to download the storage controller drivers from your computer manufacturer's website and click "load driver". Then your drive and it's partitions will show.*

[image]

6. After the last partition is deleted you should have a single instance of "unallocated space" like in the below screenshot. Select it and click the "Next" button. The Windows 10 installation will now proceed as normal.

[image]